# Escape double quotes in Smarty 3

Tags: escaping, smarty, quotes, smarty3

I'm using this code:

```
{$post->title|escape}
```

and `$post->title` contains double quotes. `<` etc are correctly escaped, but Smarty shows `"` as-is, while I expect it to show `&quot;`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a display issue with the source code and DOM view in Safari browser. Safari will display `&quot;` as `"`. Checking back with Chrome revealed that the HTML code really contains `&quot;`.